# Does Spark SQL cache the result for the same query execution

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

When I run two same queries in Spark SQL in local mode. The second run query always run faster (I assume cache locality may result this).

But when I look into Spark UI, I find out the two same queries have different number of jobs and this is the part confuses me, for example, like below.

As you could see, the second one only requires one job (20), so does this information imply Spark SQL cache the query result explicitly?
Or it caches some intermediate result of some jobs of the previous run?

Thank you for the explanation.

`collect at <console>:26+details    2019/10/09 08:28:34 2 s [20]

 collect at <console>:26+details    2019/10/09 08:26:01 2.3 min [16][17][18][19]`

Comment: If you’re running same query immediately then that is possible because spark uses LRU technique for the memory management. If you run couple of other query then it will remove the previously stored result. Now run the first query then it will take same time that it took at first time.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but when your job requires a shuffle then the intermediate results of that shuffle will be stored on all the worker nodes. These results aren't immediately removed. So when you run a similar query Spark realizes that the shuffled data is already in place and will continue from there. (This might not be the case in your situation without more details)